# Swipe cancels when table reloads data (UITableView, UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to keep `UITableView's` `UITableViewCell` that is currently swiped left or right swiped, while the table reloads its data?

I have a table that reloads data every minute to be up to date. I implemented swipes using `UITableViewDelegate` and everything worked just fine. Until the one-minute reload came and currently swiped cell went to non-swiped.

I tried saving the info which cell was last swiped by `DidEndEditing`
and `WillBeginEditing` methods - this works fine. But I found no way to programtically set the cell to "swiped state".

Of course I tried (and it works) to prevent reloads when some cell is swiped. But that's not what I want, since it leaves the table not up to date while cell is swiped.

Am I maybe missing some property of the table? Or is this simply not possible without implementing my own "delegate" and handling everything myself?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is switch off the server update inside your app till you finish the swipe action, and only after the swipe cell action ( & update server with this action, if you are updating the server with the delete action ) then only switch back on the server update. Otherwise even after the cell is updated with an action (say read/unread), a new update from server with the old data can affect your view. This is the way I used to update an email application with swipe to mark as read.

Comment: I thought of similar solution, however in my app, there are labels with time and values that change every minute. Therefore I really need these updates to happen even when cell is swiped. It's not about one or two emails missing in my case, I wouldn't mind that, its about data being literally outdated. But thanks for answer. I might accept it in the future, if there will be no other way.

Comment: This whole action will take only few seconds, if ur server is fast.

Comment: Also while swiping a cell it is better to not update the tableview, as it can cause regressions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating the cells within `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)`, you could update the views directly on the changed `UITableViewCell` subclasses.